# How to upload images from an array of paths

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, upload, ionic4

I have an array of images that are taken by the camera on the device. I want to upload these to an endpoint, I would like to know the overall progress and more importantly when they are all done.

All the examples I have found, show this process asynchronously, and the code is tightly coupled.

in my mind I would be doing the following

1. iterating the array
2. create formdata for each entry
3. call the upload service to send the image
4. finally notify the user of completion.

I followed this article

https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ a

and that did get me to the where I could upload photos but I was not able to determine when they had all finished.

is there a betterway to achive this?

This is the data that would be used to find the images

```
[
  {
    "name": "1551787085877.jpg",
    "path": "ionic://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D33A62D0-8ABE-4C0F-BCA2-CDC3F7D1A452/Library/NoCloud/1551787085877.jpg",
    "filePath": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D33A62D0-8ABE-4C0F-BCA2-CDC3F7D1A452/Library/NoCloud/1551787085877.jpg"
  }
]
```

this is my upload service code:

```
  postFaultPhoto(faultID:string , data: object): Observable<any> {
    console.log('about to post to the url')
    console.log('api/faults/' + faultID + '/photos')
    return this.http.post(environment.base_uri + 'api/faults/' + faultID + '/photos', data)
}
```

Comment: Could you post your upload service code?

Comment: @chris I have added it